# Is this fused ring molecule aromatic?

Tags: organic-chemistry, aromatic-compounds, aromaticity

[image]

In my notes, I can see that it is listed as anti-aromatic because of the 16 electron ring current that would be formed on the periphery of the entire molecule were the right benzene ring drawn in the other canonical form.

But I am not sure if that would be the case, since the two benzene rings could independently be aromatic as is the case in some other compounds.